# Using a script that exposes a global var in a Webpack build

Tags: javascript, webpack

In my (first) Webpack build I'm having trouble comprehending how I should be loading a script that simply exposes a global var.

The script I'm trying to load is basically something like this:

```
//File: MyLibrary.js    

var MyLibrary = (function(window) {

    function MyLibrary() {
        // Do librarious stuff
    }

    return MyLibrary;

})(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : null);
```

I figured I should use the `exports-loader` since according to the docs it should be just the thing for this case:

> The file sets a variable in the global context with `var XModule = ....`
>
> `var XModule = require("exports?XModule!./file.js")`

So I put this in my config:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /MyLibrary\.js$/,
            loader: "exports?MyLibrary!./MyLibrary.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

But this results in an error:

> ERROR in Loader MyLibrary.js didn't return a function

which confuses me, since it's not supposed to return a function, that's the whole point why I'm using this particular loader...

So how should I load the script?

Answer (score 2):

you don't specify the path to the library in `loader` property, simply:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /MyLibrary\.js$/,
            loader: "exports?MyLibrary"
        }
    ]
}
```